# Scroll bars disappear when switching between interaction modes?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an application that switches between touch and mouse interactions. On a as needed basis I change between the two. However, when I switch from touch to mouse the scroll bars have disappeared.

It seems like a bug. I'll post an example soon but basically just switch between modes:

```
scroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "touch");

// later: 
scroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "mouse");
// scrollers are invisible after this call
```

Example code:

```
<s:Scroller id="myScroller" top="20" right="40">
    <s:Group height="100" width="100">
        <s:Rect width="100" height="400">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="red"/>
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="blue" weight="2"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

ActionScript:

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (myScroller.getStyle("interactionMode")=="mouse") {
        myScroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "touch");
    }
    else {
        myScroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "mouse");
    }
}
```

You have to click down on the scroller and move it while it's in touch mode and then the scrollers disappear and don't reappear.

The visible and includeInLayout properties are both true after setting back to mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with some skin parts being reused but not being reset. From the [Scroller design documents](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/On-Demand%20Scrollbars/):

> The first time Scroller detects it needs to display a ScrollBar it
> will ensure one exists
>
> Scroller detects that it needs to display ScrollBar at beginning of touch interaction mode or at skin attach time if interaction mode
> is anything but "touch"
>
> If the legacy ScrollBar part already exists, the Scroller will use that one else the ScrollBar will create an instance from the factory part, set the instance to the corresponding non-factory part and call
> partAdded() for it.
>
> For example Scroller will create an instance from
> the horizontalScrollBarFactory part and will set horizontalScrollBar
> to that instance with partAdded() being called.

I've looked at all the scrollbar parts and scale, visible and includeInLayout are all true or 1. So, it seems the only way is to force it to recreate the parts.

The below is a work around. It changes the skins, validates and then changes back to the original skin:

```
if (myScroller.getStyle("interactionMode")=="mouse") {
    myScroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "touch");
}
else {      
    myScroller.setStyle("interactionMode", "mouse");
    myScroller.setStyle("skinClass", skins.MinimalScrollerSkin);
    myScroller.validateNow();
    myScroller.setStyle("skinClass", spark.skins.spark.ScrollerSkin);
}
```

Comment: What is **skins.MinimalScrollerSkin** ?

Comment: It's the Flex scroller skin for mobile that disappears and reappears but it runs on the desktop. It looks like the Mac OSX scrollbars. https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/skins/MinimalScrollerSkin.mxml